# Hibernate put in @Fetch Subselect joins

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I have an employee entity, it has related entities, I load collections using @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT), but due to the fact that I have a query with EntityGraph, all the joins that were in the previous request are added to my SUBSELECT. How can this be fixed? I tried to put the @batchSize annotation on the loaded entity, the number of requests remained the same, but the extra joins were removed. I changed the size parameter to 2, but the number of requests has not changed, apparently I do not quite understand how this annotation works, can you please tell me how to design your entity more correctly?

Main entity code:

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Where(clause = "delete_time is null")
@Table(name = "employee")
@NamedEntityGraphs({
    @NamedEntityGraph(name = "withDepartmentManagerAndOffice", attributeNodes = {
            @NamedAttributeNode("department"),
            @NamedAttributeNode("manager"),
            @NamedAttributeNode("office")
    }),
    @NamedEntityGraph(name = "withUserDepartmentManagerAndOffice", attributeNodes = {
            @NamedAttributeNode("user"),
            @NamedAttributeNode("department"),
            @NamedAttributeNode("manager"),
            @NamedAttributeNode("office")
    })
})
public class Employee extends BaseIdentifiableEntity {

@OneToOne(fetch = LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "email", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "user_email_pk"), insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ToString.Exclude
private User user;

private String email;
private String lastName;
private String firstName;
private String patronymic;
private String simpleName;//for ldap manager search

private LocalDate birthday;
private String phoneNumber;
private String telegramId;
private byte[] photo;
private String position;
private LocalDate startDate;

@ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "department_id")
@ToString.Exclude
private Department department;

@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee")
@ToString.Exclude
private List<Equipment> equipment;

@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee")
@ToString.Exclude
private List<Bonus> bonuses;

@ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "manager_id")
@ToString.Exclude
private Employee manager;

@ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "office_id")
@Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
@ToString.Exclude
private Office office;

@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee")
@ToString.Exclude
private List<Notification> notifications;

@Formula(value = "concat(last_name, ' ', first_name, ' ', patronymic)")
private String fullName;

@Transient
private String managerName;

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    if (!super.equals(o)) return false;
    Employee employee = (Employee) o;
    return Objects.equals(email, employee.email) && Objects.equals(lastName, employee.lastName) &&
           Objects.equals(firstName, employee.firstName) && Objects.equals(patronymic, employee.patronymic) &&
           Objects.equals(phoneNumber, employee.phoneNumber) && Objects.equals(telegramId, employee.telegramId) &&
           Objects.equals(position, employee.position) && Arrays.equals(photo, employee.photo) &&
           Objects.equals(startDate, employee.startDate) && Objects.equals(birthday, employee.birthday) &&
           Objects.equals(simpleName, employee.simpleName);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(super.hashCode(), email, lastName, firstName, phoneNumber, telegramId,
            Arrays.hashCode(photo), position, department, simpleName, startDate, birthday);
}
}
```

Equipment entity code:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "equipment")
@Where(clause = "delete_time is null")
public class Equipment extends NamedWithDescriptionIdentifiableEntity {

private LocalDate attachmentDate;
private String status;
private String inventoryNumber;
private String devTypeDescription;

@Where(clause = "delete_date is null")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
@ToString.Exclude
private Employee employee;

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    if (!super.equals(o)) return false;
    Equipment equipment = (Equipment) o;
    return Objects.equals(attachmentDate, equipment.attachmentDate) && Objects.equals(status, equipment.status) &&
           Objects.equals(inventoryNumber, equipment.inventoryNumber) && Objects.equals(devTypeDescription, equipment.devTypeDescription);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(super.hashCode(), attachmentDate, status, inventoryNumber, devTypeDescription);
}
}
```

Bonus entty code:

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "bonus")
@Where(clause = "delete_time is null")
public class Bonus extends NamedWithDescriptionIdentifiableEntity {

private LocalDate expirationDate;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private BonusType type;
private Long quantity;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
@ToString.Exclude
private Employee employee;

@Builder(builderMethodName = "childBuilder")
public Bonus(String name, LocalDate expirationDate, BonusType type, Long quantity, Employee employee) {
    super(name);
    this.expirationDate = expirationDate;
    this.type = type;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.employee = employee;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    if (!super.equals(o)) return false;
    Bonus bonus = (Bonus) o;
    return Objects.equals(expirationDate, bonus.expirationDate) && type == bonus.type && Objects.equals(quantity, bonus.quantity) && Objects.equals(name, bonus.name);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(super.hashCode(), expirationDate, type, quantity, name);
}
}
```

Repository metod:

```
@EntityGraph("withUserDepartmentManagerAndOffice")
@Query("SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE e.email= :email")
Optional<Employee> findFullEmployeeByEmail(String email);
```

Comment: did you try **fetch = FetchType.LAZY** ? and if you put a reproducer it will be easier to investigate.